# JSP info page debug helper

Tags: java, debugging, jsp, helper

Does anyone has uses jsp debug helper page that can be dropped into any webapp or included from within another jsp page to view header, req and session attributes?

can you please share if possible ? It will be a great help for many

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Drop `pageDebugger.jsp` in you webapp
- Access the page directly or include from another jsp like, `layout.jsp` to show this details on every page
- This page Lists following in a table

  - Request Parameters
  - Page scoped attributes and values
  - Request scoped attributes and values
  - Session scoped attributes and values
  - Application scoped attributes and values
  - Request headers
  - All Spring beans defined in the scope
  - Option to search for a resource on the classpath
- Dependency on spring framework is optional remove it if you dont use

[**pageDebugger.jsp**](https://gist.github.com/3784809)

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="500">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $paramValues</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${paramValues}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><c:forEach var="item" items="${entry.value}"
                varStatus="status">
                <pre><c:out value="${item}" /></pre>
                <c:if test="${not status.last}">
                    <br />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $requestScope</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${requestScope}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><pre><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></pre></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $sessionScope</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${sessionScope}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><pre><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></pre></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $pageScope</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${pageScope}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><pre><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></pre></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $headerValues</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${headerValues}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><c:forEach var="item" items="${entry.value}"
                varStatus="status">
                <pre><c:out value="${item}" /></pre>
                <c:if test="${not status.last}">
                    <br />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>attributes in $applicationScope</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${applicationScope}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><pre><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></pre></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>System Properties</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Set"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
    <%
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> set = p.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : set) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=e.getKey()%></td>
        <td><%="".equals(e.getValue()) ? "&nbsp;" : e.getValue()%></td>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>Spring Beans</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext"%>
    <%@page
        import="org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils"%>
    <%@page import="org.springframework.core.io.Resource"%>
    <%
        try {
            WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                    .getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
            if (springContext != null) {
                String[] beanNames = springContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
                Arrays.sort(beanNames);
                for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                    String className = springContext.getType(beanName)
                            .getName();
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=beanName%></td>
        <td><%=className%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <h3>Spring Resources</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        <form><input name="resources" size="50"/></form>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <%
        String resourceNames = request.getParameter("resources");
                if (resourceNames != null) {
                    Resource[] resources = springContext
                            .getResources(resourceNames);
                    for (Resource r : resources) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=r.getFilename()%></td>
        <td><%=r.getURI()%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally if you have option to modify web.xml, have a look at these that can also be used to monitor / profile active http session attributes

http://code.google.com/p/sessionmon/

http://messadmin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

At work I have used JDeveloper to run an application in debug mode from the IDE.  You can insert breakpoints into your .jsp and view all the debugging info.  Although, I am not a big fan of jdeveloper, it is a nice feature of the IDE.